# Forwarding messages from Kafka to Elasticsearch and Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to build an infrastructure in which I need to forward messages from one kafka topic to elasticsearch and postgresql. My infrastructure looks like in the picture below, and it all runs on the same host. Logstash is making some anonymization and some mutates, and sends the document back to kafka as json. Kafka should then forward the message to PostgreSQL and Elasticsearch

[image]

Everything works fine, accept the connection to postgresql, with which i'm having some trouble.

My config files looks like follows:

*sink-quickstart-sqlite.properties*

```
name=jdbc-test-sink
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
#table.name.format=${topic}
topics=processed

key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable:true
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter.schemas.enable:true

connection.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
connection.user=postgres
connection.password=luka
insert.mode=upsert

pk.mode=kafka

pk_fields=__connect_topic,__connect_partition,__connect_offset
fields.whitelist=ident,auth,response,request,clientip
auto.create=true
auto.evolve=true
```

*confluent-distributed.properties*

```
group.id=connect-cluster
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schemas.enable=false
offset.storage.topic=connect-offsets
offset.storage.replication.factor=1
config.storage.topic=connect-configs
config.storage.replication.factor=1
status.storage.topic=connect-status
status.storage.replication.factor=1
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000
plugin.path=/usr/share/java
```

*quicstart-elasticsearch.properties*

```
name=elasticsearch-sink
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
#topics=test-elasticsearch-sink
topics=processed
key.ignore=true
connection.url=http://localhost:9200
type.name=kafka-connect
schema.ignore=true
schemas.enable=false
```

The *confluent-schema-registry* service is running.

I'm getting the following error after *curl http://localhost:8083/connectors/jdbc-sink/status | jq*

```
{
  "name": "jdbc-sink",
  "connector": {
    "state": "RUNNING",
    "worker_id": "192.168.50.37:8083"
  },
  "tasks": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "state": "FAILED",
      "worker_id": "192.168.50.37:8083",
      "trace": "org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler
                    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:178)
                    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:104)
                    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertAndTransformRecord(WorkerSinkTask.java:488)
                    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:465)
                    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:321)
                    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:224)
                    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:192)
                    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:177)
                    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:227)
                    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
                    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
                    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
                    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
                    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
                Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: JsonConverter with schemas.enable requires \"schema\" and \"payload\" fields and may not contain additional fields. If you are trying to deserialize plain JSON data, set schemas.enable=false in your converter configuration.
                    at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.toConnectData(JsonConverter.java:359)
                    at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.Converter.toConnectData(Converter.java:86)
                    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.lambda$convertAndTransformRecord$2(WorkerSinkTask.java:488)
                    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:128)
                    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:162)
                    ... 13 more
"
    }
  ],
  "type": "sink"
}
```

This looks like a message in my "processed" topic (the message in the topic is a one-liner, this is just formated):

```
{
    "ROWTIME": 1587134287569,
    "ROWKEY": "null",
    "bytes": "4050",
    "input": {
        "type": "log"
    },
    "clientip": "156.226.170.95",
    "@timestamp": "2020-04-17T14:38:06.346Z",
    "timestamp": "17/Apr/2020:14:37:57 +0000",
    "@version": "1",
    "request": "/lists",
    "ident": "536e605f097a92cb07c2a0a81f809f481c5af00d13305f0094057907792ce65e2a62b8ab8ba036f95a840504c3e2f05a",
    "httpversion": "1.1",
    "auth": "33a7f4a829adfaa60085eca1b84e0ae8f0aa2835d206ac765c22ad440e50d7ae462adafb13306aecfdcd6bd80b52b03f",
    "agent": {
        "ephemeral_id": "053b9c29-9038-4a89-a2b3-a5d8362460fe",
        "version": "7.6.2",
        "id": "50e21169-5aa0-496f-b792-3936e9c8de04",
        "hostname": "HOSTNAME_OF_MY_AWS_INSTANCE",
        "type": "filebeat"
    },
    "log": {
        "offset": 707943,
        "file": {
            "path": "/home/ec2-user/log/apache.log"
        }
    },
    "host": {
        "name": "HOSTNAME_OF_MY_AWS_INSTANCE"
    },
    "verb": "DELETE",
    "ecs": {
        "version": "1.4.0"
    },
    "response": "503"
}
```

Please let me know if you need some more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is here:

```
DataException: JsonConverter with schemas.enable requires \"schema\" and \"payload\" fields and may not contain additional fields. If you are trying to deserialize plain JSON data, set schemas.enable=false in your converter configuration.
```

Since this is the JDBC Sink you *must* provide a schema to your data. If you have the option, I would suggest you use Avro. If not, you *must* structure your JSON data as required by Kafka Connect.

More info: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b-3qN_tlYR4&t=981s

Comment: I would use the fastest and simplest way. If I use Avro to forward the data into PostgreSQL, do I have to setup the "codec" to "avro", in my logstash output plugin config, or should I just use the Avro converter in my sink-quickstart-sqlite.properties file?

Comment: I am getting now the following error:
Caused by: java.io.CharConversionException: Invalid UTF-32 character 0x53011e31 (above 0x0010ffff) at char #1, byte #7)

Comment: I have to admit, the first time I saw you video, I didn't acutaly understood what is going on, because of lack of knowledge and so I couldn't do it by myself. After plenty of research, I watched the video again, and I've done the few commands in KSQL and everything work fine. The problem above caused the "value.converter" line in my connect-distributed.properties file, so I added these two lines in my sink-quickstart-sqlite.properties "value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter"
"value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081", and my database was filled.

Comment: Is it possible to create Streams without KSQL or can this be done explicitly by KSQL?

Comment: You can use other stream processors, e.g. Kafka Streams too.